# Data Type incorrect

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access Database that connects to three different Excel Files.

One of the Excel Files contains a column named `Commitment ID`. This field usually contains a number that is 5-9 numbers long. However there are instances where this field will be a text value such as: 344-az77.

When I open the table within Access, the numbers are shown just fine. However the records that contain text bring back a `#Num!` error.

I don't mind changing the Data Type for this column to Text - but I don't see an option to do so. Within the "Fields" Tab, under "Formatting", the "Data Type" option is greyed out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are two simple solutions:

1. Format the underlying Excel column as Text. When Access links to the Excel file, the field should come over as text.
2. Within the underlying Excel column, create a dummy row right under the column headers. Enter a string in the dummy row for the column that should be text. When Access does the linking process, it should identify the whole column as text.

There doesn't seem to be any straightforward solution in Access, however, if you do not have access to the linked Excel file, this might work:

1. In Access, use vba to call Excel, insert a schema row (after 1st row), if text, insert a string, if numeric insert a number, save it, then select via SQL, the columns will be interpreted accordingly

Comment: For anyone who stumbles across this in the future.... Converting the Excel column as text will successfully bring over all the data. However, the longer numbers will be brought over in scientific notation. I currently do not have a solution for this but have a question open https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519632/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-when-linking-excel-file-to-access